# Keep getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror, request-headers

I am writing a Python script that is trying to upload images to a server and when I run the following code snippet I keep getting the Attribute Error of 'str' object has no attribute 'items' and not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any assistance with how to write this would be much appreciated:

```
response = requests.request("GET", folder_url, headers=headers, data=payload)
jsonResponse = response.json()

for key, value in jsonResponse.items():
                print(key, ":", value)

URL = jsonResponse["presignedUrl"]
processnum = jsonResponse["processId"]

assetupload = requests.request("PUT", URL, headers='Content-Type: image/tiff', data=payload)
```

The response.json is the following:

```
This is the response.json:  {'presignedUrl': 'https://webdamuploads.s3.amazonaws.com/13870_d944a723_4232_4892_bdfd_26dd73edec44.tif?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJBNEEVWEAALCCECQ%2F20200806%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200806T163417Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=180&X-Amz-Signature=2856c1a615b88a91fc6c9fee02eae2a051b60b902660d04890d795057dd097e3', 'processId': '200483605'}
```

The Traceback error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jphelps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\jphelps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\jphelps\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\jphelps\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\jphelps\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\jphelps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\jphelps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\jphelps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "l:\ISG Documentation\Python\individual scripts\upload_asset_to_webdam.py", line 122, in <module>
    assetupload = requests.request("PUT", URL, headers='Content-Type:image/tiff', data=payload)
  File "C:\Users\jphelps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jphelps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 516, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\jphelps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 449, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\jphelps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 315, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "C:\Users\jphelps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 447, in prepare_headers
    for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: can you include the `response.json()` in your post.

Comment: @VishalSingh I added the response.json to the post.  It is from an API that gives me a URL and a process id that is need to load the image.  I am supposed to use that presigned URL in a PUT statement with the Content-Type.

Comment: this should not raise errors. can you also include the error traceback

Comment: have you tried printing `jsonResponse` and verifying it?

Comment: the error is coming from the assetupload line.  What is it about that line that could be causing this?  Printing jsonResponse gives me the response.json.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your issue in python by given code

```
jsonResponse={'presignedUrl': 'https://webdamuploads.s3.amazonaws.com/13870_d944a723_4232_4892_bdfd_26dd73edec44.tif?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJBNEEVWEAALCCECQ%2F20200806%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200806T163417Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=180&X-Amz-Signature=2856c1a615b88a91fc6c9fee02eae2a051b60b902660d04890d795057dd097e3', 'processId': '200483605'}
for key, value in jsonResponse.items():
                print(key, ":", value)
a=jsonResponse["presignedUrl"]
print(a)
```

and i got

```
presignedUrl : https://webdamuploads.s3.amazonaws.com/13870_d944a723_4232_4892_bdfd_26dd73edec44.tif?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJBNEEVWEAALCCECQ%2F20200806%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200806T163417Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=180&X-Amz-Signature=2856c1a615b88a91fc6c9fee02eae2a051b60b902660d04890d795057dd097e3
processId : 200483605
https://webdamuploads.s3.amazonaws.com/13870_d944a723_4232_4892_bdfd_26dd73edec44.tif?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJBNEEVWEAALCCECQ%2F20200806%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200806T163417Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=180&X-Amz-Signature=2856c1a615b88a91fc6c9fee02eae2a051b60b902660d04890d795057dd097e3
```

The possibility of araising this problem is when you trying to do `.items` action on str. like given below

```
jsonResponse='hellow world'
for key, value in jsonResponse.items():
                print(key, ":", value)
a=jsonResponse["presignedUrl"]
print(a)
```

which will raise an error

```
   for key, value in jsonResponse.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: how do I fix this?

Comment: Have u checked the line `for header in headers.items()`